Flutter web grey screen due to service worker caching in production
I'm encountering a grey screen issue in my Flutter web app after deploying a new version to production. Users report seeing a grey screen during navigation, which I believe is caused by the service worker caching the old UI.
I've come across a related GitHub issue where this problem was discussed, but despite trying the suggested workarounds (including modifying service worker by customizing flutter_bootstrap.js file) the issue persists with newer Flutter versions and the updated web app initialization process (project's SDK version is 3.24.1).
Customized flutter_bootstrap.js:
{{flutter_js}}
{{flutter_build_config}}

_flutter.loader.load({
  serviceWorkerSettings: {
    serviceWorkerVersion: {{flutter_service_worker_version}},
  },
  onEntrypointLoaded: async function (engineInitializer) {
    const appRunner = await engineInitializer.initializeEngine();

    await appRunner.runApp();
  },
});


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Could you once check with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78152396/how-do-i-replace-serviceworkerversion-with-flutter-service-worker-version
I think here you will find the solution

@AnkitaSharma This is a completely different problem, I added what I have tried already to the question for more details.
